# Checking if a registry key exists python

Tags: python, installation, registry, winreg

I am encountering a small hiccup in the installer I am creating in python. I have a function which returns the value of a key based on it's location.

```
def CheckRegistryKey(registryConnection, location, softwareName, keyName):
'''
Check the windows registry and return the key value based on location and keyname
'''    
    try:
        if registryConnection == "machine":
            aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
        elif registryConnection == "user":
            aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_CURRENT_USER)   
        aKey = OpenKey(aReg, location)
    except Exception, ex:
        print ex
        return False

    try:
        aSubKey=OpenKey(aKey,softwareName)
        val=QueryValueEx(aSubKey, keyName)
        return val
    except EnvironmentError:
        pass
```

I get an error if the location does not exist. I want the function to return `False` so if the location does not exist so I can run the software installer, bit it always lands up in the exception

```
# check if the machine has .VC++ 2010 Redistributables and install it if needed
try:
    hasRegistryKey = (edit_registry.CheckRegistryKey("machine", r"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist", "x86", "Installed"))
    if hasRegistryKey != False:
        keyCheck = (edit_registry.CheckRegistryKey("machine", r"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist", "x86", "Installed"))[0]
        if keyCheck == 1:   
            print 'vc++ 2010 redist installed'
    else:
        print 'installing VC++ 2010 Redistributables'
        os.system(productsExecutables + 'vcredist_x86.exe /q /norestart')
        print 'VC++ 2010 Redistributables installed'
except Exception, ex:
    print ex
```

The exception I get when I run the code is

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '___getitem___'
```

and the error I get from the `def CheckRegistryKey` function is

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What I need to do is check if the registry key or location exists, if not direct it to an executable. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '___getitem___'
```

Is in the line:

```
keyCheck = (edit_registry.CheckRegistryKey("machine", r"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist", "x86", "Installed"))[0]
```

The fragment `edit_registry.CheckRegistryKey("machine", r"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist", "x86", "Installed")` is returning `None`.

This means you end up with:

```
keyCheck = (None)[0]
```

This is what is throwing your error. You are trying to get an item on a object that is None.

The reason that this you are getting `None` back from your `CheckRegistryKey` function is that if an error occurs you aren't returning anything. You need to `return False` when you catch a `EnvironmentError`:

```
try:
    aSubKey=OpenKey(aKey,softwareName)
    val=QueryValueEx(aSubKey, keyName)
    return val
except EnvironmentError:
    return False
```

I would also modify your code so that you are only calling `CheckRegistryKey` once:

```
registryKey = edit_registry.CheckRegistryKey("machine", r"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist", "x86", "Installed")
if registryKey is not False:
    keyCheck = registryKey[0]
```